# Prove: If $A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}, \text{ then }\sup (A + B) = \sup (A) + \sup (B)$, where $A,B$ are bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I know there are other threads in this site that gives alternate proofs to this. However, I was hoping to see if you thought my approach (which I don't see on this site yet) is valid. The proof follows:

$\exists \ \bar{a} \in A \ \text{ s.t. } \ \forall a \in A, \ \bar{a} \geq a$ and $\ \bar{a} \leq \sup (A)$. Similarly,  $\exists \ \bar{b} \in B \ \text{ s.t. } \ \forall b \in B, \bar{b} \geq b$ and $\bar{b} \leq \sup(B)$. It follows that $\exists \ \bar{c}=\bar{a}+\bar{b}  \in A+B \ \text{ s.t. } \ \forall c \in A+B, \ \bar{c} \geq c $ and $\bar{c} \leq \sup(A) + \sup (B)$. This establishes that $\sup (A) + \sup (B)$ is an upper bound for $A+B$. We also know that if $a' < \sup (A), \exists  \ a \in A \text{ s.t. } a>a'$. Similarly, if $ b' < \sup(B), \ \exists \ b \in B \text{ s.t. } b>b'$ $\therefore \exists \ c \in A+B \text{ s.t. } c > \sup(A)+b', \ c>a'+\sup(B), \ \text{ and } c>a'+b' \implies \sup (A+B) = \sup(A)+\sup(B)$.

Comment: The first line seems wrong.  Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be the set of real numbers $x<1$.  Then of course $\sup A = 1$, but there is no $\overline a\in A$ which has the properties you claim.

Comment: It is not true (in general) that for a given $A$ there is some $\bar{a} \in A$ such that $\bar{a} \ge a$ for all $a \in A$, consider for instance $]0,1[$

Comment: The first line is simply false. Completely and totally. The fact that such points *don't* always exist (such an element is a maximum element and they certainly don't exist on open intervals or most open sets) is precisely *why* we have the concept of supremas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line itself is incorrect in two places.

First of all, you are saying that there is an $\bar a \in A$ such that for all $a \in A$, $\bar a \geq a$. This is incorrect, there are umpteen counterexamples, some given above. Yes, the $\bar a$ may be there, but there's no guarantee it will be in $A$  itself.

Furthermore, by what you have given, $\bar a$ is an *upper bound* of the set $A$, and the supremum of $A$ is the **least** *upper bound*, so $\sup A \leq \bar a$ should follow, and not the other way. The same two wrongs have been made for $b$, and they certainly don't make a right.

What you are getting correct is the idea : you first want to prove that $\sup A + \sup B$ is *an* upper bound , then that it is the *least* upper bound.

To show that it is *an* upper bound, it's enough to show for all $a \in A$, $b \in B$, that $a + b \leq \sup A + \sup B$. But then, $\sup A \geq  a$ and $\sup B \geq b$, so this follows straight away.

From here, you need to show that it is indeed the least upper bound. This procedure will tell you how to do it.You can keep it in mind if you encounter a similar question.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. As $\sup A - \frac\epsilon 2$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$, there is an element $a_0 \in A > \sup A - \frac\epsilon 2$.

Similarly, there is an element $b_0 > \sup B - \frac\epsilon 2$.

Adding these up, $a_0 + b_0 > \sup A + \sup B - \epsilon$.

So, *for all $\epsilon > 0$*, $\sup A + \sup B - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A+B$. So the least upper bound is at least $\sup A + \sup B$, but we've already seen this is an upper bound, so it follows it's the least upper bound.

Hence, the lemma is proven.

Now, you can use this procedure to try and prove that the supremum of the set $\{a \times b : a \in A, b \in B\}$ is $\sup A \sup B$, for $A, B$ subsets of *positive real numbers*.

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful. I tried to prove the question you posed. I got to a point where $\epsilon$ must be less than $\sup (A) + \sup(B)$ for the proof to make sense. Specifically, the last line of the proof i have so far states: $a_0 \cdot b_0 > (\sup(A) - \epsilon) \cdot (\sup(B) - \epsilon) = \sup(A) \sup(B) - \epsilon (\sup(A) + \sup(B)-\epsilon) $. If $\epsilon > \sup(A)+\sup(B)$, $ \epsilon (\sup(A) + \sup(B)-\epsilon)$ becomes negative, which causes this term to be added to the product of sups. Full attempt is in next comment. Can you please tell me how to proceed?

Comment: $\forall a \in A, \ \sup (A) \geq a \text{ and } \forall b \in B, \ \sup (B) \geq b \implies \forall c \in A\times B, \ \sup (A) \cdot \sup (B) \geq c$. Let $\epsilon>0$. We know $\sup (A) - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $A \implies \ \exists \ a_0 \in A \text{ s.t. } a_0 > \sup(A)-\epsilon$. Similarly, $\exists b_0 \in B \text{ s.t. } b_0 > \sup (B) - \epsilon$. Now, $a_0 \cdot b_0 > (\sup(A) - \epsilon) \cdot (\sup(B) - \epsilon) = \sup(A) \sup(B) - \epsilon (\sup(A) + \sup(B)-\epsilon) $.

Comment: If we assume that  $\epsilon<1$ (we need to take $\epsilon$ close to zero,  so this is fine),  then we have that $\sup A + \sup B - \epsilon \leq \sup A  + \sup B - 1$, which is some fixed constant. Now, the proof is basically to repeat the same argument, with $\epsilon$ replaced by $\frac \epsilon{\sup A + \sup  B -1}$. You will get the same  thing, but with $\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon (\sup A + \sup B  - \epsilon)$. Then, you are done.

Comment: I don't see why $\epsilon<1 \implies \sup A + \sup B - \epsilon \leq \sup A + \sup B -1$. Shouldn't the inequality be the other way?

Comment: @lasoon Big mistake on my part. Instead, just take $\sup A + \sup B - \epsilon < \sup A + \sup B$. Then it should work out.